# Redirect to URL with trailing slash doesn't occur in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: url, redirect, websphere, trailing-slash, contextpath

There is an application that works on WAS7. It has war module deployed on context path "Foo/Bar" (compound one). That is the war module is accessible via the URL like this: localhost:9080/Foo/Bar.

Then I deployed the same application on WAS 8.5.5. Trying to access war module with the same URL localhost:9080/Foo/Bar (without trailing slash) and getting the "bare" page without css and js files retrieved. However, when I try to access module via the following URL localhost:9080/Foo/Bar/ (with trailing slash) css and js get picked up correctly.

What I was able to figure out so far, is that on WAS 7 everything worked because there was redirect from URL with no trailing slash to URL with trailing slash. And it seems like it is normal behavior http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/why-urls-end-in-slash.htm. The question is why don't I have the same behavior on WAS 8.5.5 ? Is there any way to configure it?

Comment: The property  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.removetrailingservletpathslash (as true or false) as documented in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frweb_custom_props.html works on Websphere 8.0 too and probably in 8.5, but i dont have an 8.5 server to test.

Comment: Martin, for some reasons I can't find this property by following the link that you provided, but I tried adding it with 'false' and 'true' values just in case but it didn't help with my issue

Answer (score 2):

Use documented in [WAS9 Custom Properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html#redirectcontextroot)

> **com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.redirectcontextroot**
>
> If set to true, and a request is made to the context root of an application with a missing trailing slash, the WebContainer appends the trailing slash. The WebContainer redirects to the URL with the appended slash before it applies any servlet filters defined in the application.
>
> For example, a request to http://host:port/contextRoot is redirected to http://host:port/contextRoot/ before any filters are applied.
>
> Name: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.redirectcontextroot,
>   Default value: false

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time debugging Websphere classes and found one property which I believe is the answer to my question: `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.redirectcontextroot`. Bad news is that I can't find it to be mentioned in documentation related to WebContainer custom properties of Websphere.

So now redirect works as I expect but I'm confused with the fact that I'm using some undocumented feature...

Comment: Can you explain how to set that property on WAS?